# Evaluate string "a+b+c" as an actual sum of numbers in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

i'm trying to make a script that reads a file of comma separated values like this:

> 10,20,30,40
>
> 30,50,20,80

I want it to get every line and print the result of adding all the numbers in it, kind of like applying the map function, there's probably a lot of better ways to do this, but I'm curious to now if this is possible:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line; do
    field=$line 
    result=$(echo $line | tr ',' '+')
    echo $(expr $result)    #Here i would have the string "10+20+30+40"
done < <(cat "$1")
```

What I want is to get the result of adding those instead of the string, I don't know if that's possible.
Sorry for the messy explanation.

Comment: note `< <(cat "$1")` is not necessary, `< "$1"` suffices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a space between the `+` and the numbers. Instead do:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line; do
    field=$line 
    result=$(echo $line | sed 's/,/ + /g')
    echo $(expr $result)   
done < "$1"
```

You also don't need to `cat $1`, you can redirect it straight into the loop.

Comment: Was just going to post this, you may also want to put a condition in front of `echo $(expr $result)` to prevent the expr error message when it gets no input.

Comment: This was perfect, to make the question easier to ask and clearer I used integers instead of decimal numbers and that was a little problem, but I solved it, and your question was perfect for the question I asked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bc`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line; do
    echo $line | tr ',' '+' | bc
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Loved this question cause it works with decimals as well! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the Arithmetic expansion `$((...))` instead of `expr`:

```
while read -r line ; do
    result=${line//,/+}
    echo $(($result))
done < "$1"
```

I also used Parameter expansion instead of `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in one-line with `awk` :

```
awk -F, '$0 {s=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i; print s}' "$1"
```

Output:

```
100
180
```

Explanation:

- `-F,` : set `,`  as the field separator
- `$0 {..}` : Make sure the line (`$0`) is not empty
- Finally, sum up all the fields (`s+=$i`) for each line

Answer (score 0):

You can use split the values into an array, then use a simple loop to iterate over the array and add the values.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line; do
    IFS=, read -a values <<< "$line"
    result=0
    for i in ${values[@]}; do
       result=$((result + i))
    done
    echo "$result"
done < "$1"
```

A shorter, but more cryptic, method is to use `bash` parameter expansion to convert each comma to a space-surrounded plus sign, then pass the resulting *unquoted* expansion to `expr`.

```
while IFS='' read -r line; do
    expr ${line//,/ + }
done
```